# Stacked vertical bar chart in subplot

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to build a stacked vertical bar chart with plotly js but am having trouble with the syntax. Whenever I add trace3 to the data array the chart seems to merge all charts together.
Here is a bit of context to the graphic:

- I'm trying to show the relationship between price and the number of returns in a month
- The graph on the left is a stacked bar chart showing the number of products purchased vs the number of products returned
- The right hand side shows the average price delta of that month

Here is what I've achieved so far: https://codepen.io/andscool/pen/RwqydVW

It seems like the data array attempts to merge all charts into one (ignoring my grid specifications) when I insert this code into

```
var trace3 = {
    x: [2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    y: ["2023.06", "2023.04", "2023.05", "2023.01", "2023.03", "2023.02", "2022.12"],
    name: 'Returns',
    orientation: 'h',
    type: 'bar',
    xaxis: 'x3',
    yaxis: 'y3',
}

var data = [trace1, trace3, trace2];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
FYI, here are my sources:

- Bar charts: https://plotly.com/javascript/bar-charts/
- Subplots: https://plotly.com/javascript/subplots/#simple-subplot

Please let me know if any information is missing.

Edit:
I'm trying to go for something like this (a picture paints a thousand words :P )

[image]

Comment: _A picture paints a thousand words :P_. Definitely. Thanks for the clarification, I was missing the point. I edited my answer since then but not sure you've seen it or even got notified..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace ordering in the data array has no effect on their placement in the layout. In order to stack trace 1 and trace 3 together, let them refer to the same axes and set `barmode: 'stack'` in the layout.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [140, 3, 17, 4, 61, 33, 47],
  y: ["2023.06", "2023.05", "2023.04", "2023.03", "2023.02", "2023.01", "2022.12"],
  type: 'bar',
  orientation: 'h',
  xaxis: 'x1',
  yaxis: 'y1',
  text: ["140 75%", "3", "17", "4", "61", "33", "47"]
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  y: ["2023.06", "2023.04", "2023.05", "2023.01", "2023.03", "2023.02", "2022.12"],
  name: 'Returns',
  orientation: 'h',
  type: 'bar',
  xaxis: 'x1',
  yaxis: 'y1',
}

var trace2 = {
  x: [-50, -3, 17, -4, -61, 33, 47],
  y: ["2023.06", "2023.04", "2023.05", "2023.01", "2023.03", "2023.02", "2022.12"],
  xaxis: 'x2',
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'bar',
  orientation: 'h',
  text: ["-50€", -3, 17, -4, -61, 33, 47]
};

var data = [trace1, trace3, trace2];

var layout = {
  barmode: 'stack',
  showlegend: false,
  grid: {rows: 1, columns: 2, pattern: 'independent'},
  xaxis1: {
    title: "Anzahl der Produkten (n)",
    showticklabels: true,
    showgrid: true,
  },
  yaxis1: {
    type: "category",
    tickmode:"array",
    tickvals: ["2023.02","2023.03","2023.01","2023.05","2023.04","2023.06", "2022.12"],
    ticktext:["2023.02","2023.03","2023.01","2023.05","2023.04","2023.06", "2022.12"]
  },
  xaxis2: {
    title: "Euro (€)"
  },
  yaxis2: {
    type: "category",
    showticklabels: false
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.24.1.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey Eric, this is exactly what I was after. Thank you! If I could, I would upvote this even more.